# How to access (reference) custom itemRenderer in TileList?

Tags: apache-flex

I have a TileList cp with 10 item.
How can i call a function in 4. item (for example) from outside, where i created a TileList cp?

Thanks

Comment: Typically, you don't access an specific itemRenderer in your list. You'll access the data behind the itemRenderer in your dataProvider. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I have to call a function in all item in TileList.

Comment: you have to call in a function on the items in the TileList or on the renderers?  If you have to call a function on the items; you need access to the dataProvider; not actual renderers.

Comment: There are a TileList, with itemRenderer.
The dataProvider have 10 node, so 10 item generating, when run the application. I have to call a function from outside, what these items have.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

Based on your comments, this should be even easier. You would just loop through each of the rows in your List's dataProvider and make whatever changes are necessary. At the end of the function just call the `refresh` function on the ArrayCollection. Using my example below:

```
public function myFunction(evt:Event):void
{
  for each (var o:MyObject in myDataProvider)
  {
    o.someProperty = "Updated";
  }

  myArrayCollection.refresh();
}
```

After the ArrayCollection is updated, calling the `refresh` function should cause the List to refresh its item renderers as well.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

It sounds like you want to call a function outside your `ItemRenderer` when a button or something is clicked in the `ItemRenderer` but still be able to access the data for the item that was clicked.

Assuming I've got this correct, you still wouldn't need to access the `ItemRenderer` itself. You can just do something like this (just a rough example):

```
<fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[

  public function myFunction(evt:Event):void
  {
    trace(MyObject(myList.selectedItem).someProperty.toString());
  }

  ]]>
</fx:Script>

<mx:List id="myList" dataProvider="{myDataProvider}" >
  <mx:itemRenderer>
    <fx:Component>
      <mx:CheckBox selectedField="IsSelected" change="outerDocument.myFunction(event);" />
    </fx:Component>
  </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:List>
```

If you *do* need to pass a completely separate parameter that's not stored in your List's dataProvider, just pass it as an argument to the change eventHandler.

```
change="outerDocument.myFunction(event, someOtherValue);"
```

Comment: Not exactly.With your example: I would like to call a function in all items, not just in selected item.

So, there is a function in itemRenderer, call: changeSomething().
This function is change something in the items.. So, i would like to change something in all items, not just selected item.

I need something like this:
(MyObject(myList.allItem).someProperty.toString());

Comment: @johnyflex I updated my answer based on your comments. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: I have Tilelist(id: myTileList), ItemRenderer(id: myItemRenderer), dataProvider(id: myDataProvider:XMLList), can you write your code with specific for my names, because i don't understand fully..Thanks!